# How can Rpi3B read the CJMCU-8128 (CCS811 + HDC1080 + BMP280) 3 in 1 sensors module?

Tags: pi-zero-w, sensor

I've got a CJMCU-8128 board with CCS811 + HDC1080 + BMP280 sensors.

[image]

There is an explanation how to wire it here: https://www.strawdogs.co/2018/07/Using-the-CJMCU-8128-Breakout-Environment-Sensor-Board/

And a repo with different python modules here: https://github.com/OdinsHat/cjmcu-8128-sensor-breakout

My problem is, that only the HDC1000 sensor works for me.

`i2cdetect` detects devices at `40`, `5a` and `76` just like in the blog post. Running [testHDC1000.py](https://github.com/switchdoclabs/SDL_Pi_HDC1000/blob/6e6a2d0cef09f0286a7841b5ae87b124177112b6/testHDC1000.py) gives me (probably correct) temperature and humidity values.

But when I run [ccs811.py](https://github.com/OdinsHat/cjmcu-8128-sensor-breakout/blob/master/examples/ccs811.py) I get on the first run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ccs811.py", line 40, in <module>
    ccs811example()
  File "ccs811.py", line 13, in ccs811example
    c02, tvoc, temp = getdata()
  File "ccs811.py", line 20, in getdata
    temp = ccs.calculateTemperature()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Adafruit_CCS811/Adafruit_CCS811.py", line 185, in calculateTemperature
    rntc = (float(vrntc) * float(CCS811_REF_RESISTOR) / float(vref) )
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

and on any further run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ccs811.py", line 40, in <module>
    ccs811example()
  File "ccs811.py", line 13, in ccs811example
    c02, tvoc, temp = getdata()
  File "ccs811.py", line 19, in getdata
    ccs = Adafruit_CCS811()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Adafruit_CCS811/Adafruit_CCS811.py", line 92, in __init__
    raise Exception("Device returned an Error! Try removing and reapplying power to the device and running the code again.")
Exception: Device returned an Error! Try removing and reapplying power to the device and running the code again.
```

until I disconnect and reconnect the sensor. Then I get the division by zero error on the first run again.

Running [bme280.py](https://github.com/OdinsHat/cjmcu-8128-sensor-breakout/blob/master/examples/ccs811.py) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bme280.py", line 44, in <module>
    bme280example()
  File "bme280.py", line 11, in bme280example
    (temp, pressure, humidity) = getdata()
  File "bme280.py", line 27, in getdata
    degrees = sensor.read_temperature()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Adafruit_BME280.py", line 215, in read_temperature
    UT = float(self.read_raw_temp())
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Adafruit_BME280.py", line 194, in read_raw_temp
    self.BME280Data = self._device.readList(BME280_REGISTER_DATA, 8)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 136, in readList
    results = self._bus.read_i2c_block_data(self._address, register, length)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 216, in read_i2c_block_data
    cmdstring[i] = val
TypeError: one character string expected
```

I've read some (german) [blogpost](https://sanduhrgucker.de/2020/05/06/ohne-stress-den-ad-wandler-ads1115-mit-arduino-pi-zu-nutzen/) that says I should replace the line with `cmdstring[i] = str(val)`, but this does not help either.

Comment: Your I2C communication might not be reliable, especially if you from time to time gets the "I/O Error #121". So Both CCS811 and BME280 are making trouble. You might like to lower I2C speed (only if you are using Rpi4B) to 50kHz for a more reliable performance.  There are other tricks such as removing all other I2C devices, AND removing all pull up resistors of every I2C modules. You might like to read App A of my answer to the following more troubleshooting suggestions: "Rpi BMP180  problem":
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60274562/raspberry-pi-sensor-detection-not-working. Cheers.

Comment: I already lowered the speed to 10000 baud according to this [Adafruit howto for the CCS811](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ccs811-air-quality-sensor/raspberry-pi-wiring-test). I am using a Pi 3B and this combined module is the only sensor that is connected to the pi. Things I could try: 1) lower the baud rate even more (I am not sure if this should work) 2) Use 5V power instead of 3,3.

Comment: thank you for your clarification. Your 3 in 1 module is a bit completed. Let me read the datasheet and user guide to get a better, and then come back you.  It might take me a couple of days. But first some quick comments. (1) If i2cdetect -y 1 can detect all 3 devices's addresses, then it is 90% sure that I2C hardware wiring and software setup are more or less OK. It is 90% unlikely that the problem will disappear even if you improve I/O performance by lowering speed, shift 3V3 signal to 5V, shorter wiring, removing other devices, removing module pull ups.

Comment: (2) I think the problem is in software: (a) AdaFruit software might be out of date and not compatible for newer Rpi hardware and/or software (not an uncommon thing), (b) especially you are using their Ciccuit Python, which I know if not very Rpi compatible.

Comment: The three devices in the 3 in 1 module are common things. Perhaps we can try NOT to use AdaFruit software, but other open hardware vendor's tutorials and see there is any luck. Let me draft something as the research part of a tentative answers. As I said, might take a couple of days.

Comment: Now let me summarize (1)  SwitchDocLab's HDC100 program runs OK, (2) No luck on AdaFruit's ccs811.py and bm280.py. I would suggest to ***first troubleshoot BM280.py.***

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive analysis so far. There really seem to be different libraries and test programs and I do not have a good overview which ones may be better than other ones, yet. I will debug these things a bit later when I have more time, but your post looks very helpful.

Comment: When it helps can I test using a NodeMCU (ESP8266) board (there seemt to be Arduino libraries for some of the sensors as well), but I eventually want to run the application using a pi, so I can process the data on the same device.

Comment: Yes, I agree. ESP8266-12 is too small, though you can use ESP32 which is much more powerful, but still small comparing with Rpi4B. I once tried ESP8266-12 but found NodeMCU LUA is very hard to use, while microPython is is too weak. Also ESP8266 IDE is not mature at atl. So I spent some 100 hours playing with it and then gave up.

Comment: Rpi python is very good in prototyping. Just now I read my old post on programming HTC1080 and found it not to hard, of course because the chip itself is simple. I ordered CCS811 module a day ago and it arrives today. So I will skip BME280 and start playing with CCS811 now.

Comment: Please read Appendix J of my answer for the bad news that AdaFruit CCS811 Library has deprecated. The new AdaFruit library is for Circuit Python which I know is not compatible to Rpi.  I am now googling to find another library, hopefully from Piromori.

Comment: Just now  I casually googled and found a couple of CCS811 python libraries. The one that impresses me most is from ***SparkFun***. I have appended the References 31~33 in the reference list of my answer. I plan to try it tomorrow. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment as I haven't got the reputation points yet. But I noticed you're running Python 2.7 and most of the Adafruit libraries require Python 3.

check with

```
sudo python --version
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3 git python3-pip
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python $(which python2) 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python $(which python3) 2
```

and then

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

just to confirm that py3 is now your default, and you can check again with..

```
sudo python --version
```

with that said...I did this and I'm not even getting as far as you and haven't been able to find a datasheet like the CCS811 which I feel comfortable enough reverse engineering to suit my needs but I'm nearly tempted to just put this down as a learning expense and go buy the CCS811 (which is what I wanted in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the problem with the BME280...don’t replace

```
cmdstring[i] = val
```

with

```
cmdstring[i] = str(val)
```

but with

```
cmdstring[i] = chr(val)
```

That worked for me.